# How do I use the value of numbers of documents?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the number of documents in a specific collection. I'm retrieving it through the snapshot, as it gives me the correct number. But when I want to return it through my function, it returns `0`.

I then tried to do some console printing, and it looks like the return value is printed first (`1`), then it goes back and print the values inside the request, where my second print status is (`2`). How can I make it return the correct (or the `snapshot.count` value)?

My counter is declared in the start of the `ViewController` like this:

```
var counter: Int = 0
```

Here is my code:

```
func checkDayNumber() -> String {
    let ref = db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("startDay").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error getting documents for checking number of days")
        } else {
            print(snapshot?.count)
            if let count = snapshot?.count {
                self.counter = count
                print(self.counter) (2)
          }
        }
      }
    print(counter) (1)
    return String(counter)
}
```

Console:

> 0
>   2

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting data from the firebase server and it's an `asynchronous` call and you need to wait until you got response from the server.

So in your case when you call `checkDayNumber` method `print(counter) (1)` will return before your API Call completes so it will return `0`

now still your API call is going on and once firebase server return a result your `print(self.counter) (2)` will return 2.

So to solve this problem you can use `closures` for that.

[Here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f) is it explained.